# Pass variables scope from another controller angualrjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to pass scope variables in a controller to another controller. I've been try, but still not working.this is my code:

```
.factory('MyService',function(){
   return {varId_agen:''};
})
.controller('InputEditCtrl',function($scope,MyService){
   $scope.MyService=MyService;
   $scope.id_agen = $scope.MyService;
})
.controller('dataBusCtrl',function($scope,Buses,$timeout,TxData,$ionicModal,MyService){
   $scope.editData = function(dataBus){
      Service.varId_agen= dataBus.id_agen;
      $scope.editModal.show();
   };
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use setter and getter methods in a service to achieve so, check this code
    `

```
angular.module('myApp', []).factory('myService', function () {
var o = {x:1, y:2};
return {
    getO: getO,
    setO: setO
};

function getO() {
    return o;
}
function setO(x, y) {
    o.x = x;
    o.y = y;
}
```

});

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrlA', function ($scope, myService) {
myService.setO(3, 4);
});

angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrlB', function ($scope, myService) {
var o = myService.getO(); // {x:3, y:4}
  });    `
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :), its work, but setO cant work in scope function, why? sorry im new in angular

Comment: It will Work u myt be doing some mistake implement it in the following way as ever u want                                    '      app.factory('entryid',function(){
       var entry=[{expid:0}];
            return{
  getid:function(){
  return entry.expid;
 },
 setid:function (exid){
  entry.expid=exid;
 }};
     });'